# javascript display htmlentities tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var foo = $('.imgEscape').text();
foo = foo.replace("&lt;img src=&quot;", "<img src='");
foo = foo.replace("&quot; /&gt;", "' />");
$('.imgEscape').text(foo);//will display as string
$('.imgEscape').html(foo);//will display all html tag

&lt;img src=&quot;https://www.google.com.tw/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png&quot; /&gt;
&lt;b&gt;abc&lt;/b&gt
```

I have a page backend output data as htmlspecialcharacter.

I wish to use js to replace some tag (ex. img tag)

so I can still display image

my problem is if I use `html()`, it will display all element.

I wish to display image only (`<img> ... &lt;b&gt;abc&lt;/b&gt`)

anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Can you post a url which has your code deployed like a js fiddle or code pen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method returns the parsed text data so [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method is doing nothing since the content is parsed string. Instead you need to get the actual `HTML` content content using [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method .

```
var foo = $('.imgEscape').html();
// update here -----------^^^^^^----
foo = foo.replace("&lt;img src=&quot;", "<img src='");
foo = foo.replace("&quot; /&gt;", "' />");
$('.imgEscape').html(foo);
```

Comment: wait i found the problem, quote didnt display &quot; when i use html()